# gSheet - Google Apps Script - copy DataValidation - Dropdown: "Loading ..."

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Via Google Apps Script I am copying Data Validation rules from a range with one col to several cols offsetted to said one. Its been done on a freshly duplicated sheet - also by script (with: `.insertSheet(newSheetName, {template: sheet});`)

Code to copy data validations from one col to the next on the right:

[image]

Seems to execute somehow. However, when I want to use the dropdown on that cells to select a data point I just shows a field "Loading ..."

When checking the data validation via the gui the right named range is set as the "list of a range".

[image]

Even when then resetting it manually it still shows that "Loading ..." field.

Whats wrong there?

Comment: No images of code